# Advantages of Lambda calculus over Turing machine and vice versa

Tags: turing-machines, computability, lambda-calculus

What kind of advantages does Lambda calculus have over Turing machine, and vice versa?

Comment: This question is a fine one to discuss over a beer, but it's really primarily asking for opinions, and as such is not appropriate. You should give more context and explain what sort of *technical* aspect of the question you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda calculus and Turing machines are equivalent models of computation, each of which formally captures the informal notion of effective calculation (this is the Church-Turing thesis). The lambda calculus is a more abstract and algebraic approach, whereas Turing machines offer a more concrete, algorithmic approach.